# Content section not showing in view menu SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2016, ssrs-2016

I just installed SSRS 2016 (SQLServer2016-x64-ENU.iso ) and noticed that there was no section "Content" in view menu. I have full rights.

SSRS 2016 menu
[image: SSRS 2016 menu]

The proper menu consists "Content" section
[image: The proper menu consists "Content" section]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This menu is context driven. It will only show those options when you have a project or solution loaded and a report selected

Comment: I update proper screenshot. There aren't any objects like datasets, mobile reports etc. However I have these objects in my project.

Comment: Can you change the image of your issue to show the whole window too?

Comment: I changed the image.

Comment: Yes I see your problem, but I don't have any more ideas. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Some SSRS 2016 preview releases had that "Content" menu, but SSRS 2016 RTM does not. As an administrator, you can control which items users see by assigning permissions, and as a user, you see everything you have permission to see.